# Как лучше реализовать сохранение параметров текста для печати через Graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Есть текстовый редактор, в котором есть `JTabbedPane tabs` на каждой вкладке этого `JTabbedPane` Текстовое поле `JTextPane`. Можно менять шрифт текста, цвет, стиль. Хочу реализовать печать с помощью `Graphics`. Как лучше хранить параметры для печати. У меня одна мысль: Создать что-то типа:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList> tabsParametrList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Font> fontsOnTab =new ArrayList<>();
// Ну и добавить шрифты
```

Недостатков такого подхода очень много. Придется городить ArrayList содержащий несколько ArrayList-ов с цветами и шрифтом для каждой вкладки, а потом брать параметры как-то типа:

```
  Graphics2D g = new Graphics2D();
  g.setFont(tabsParametrList.get(tabs.getSelectedIndex()).get(0));
```

Ну а самое главное, я не придумал, как сопоставить шрифты и цвета с текстом. Может у кого есть идеи получше, как реализовать такую печать? спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Создайте класс, который содержит шрифт, цвет и стиль(или что вам еще надо). От него ArrayList и создавайте. Ну, и, конечно же, создайте метод печати в этом классе

Comment: @Miron А может как-то использовать StyledDocument?